# How to force Emma code coverage report to ignore some methods?

Tags: code-coverage, emma

Some methods, such as auto-generated getters, setters, equals and toString, are trivial for test. However, if they aren't added into the testing classes, the code coverage percentage (calculated using Emma) is reduced and may crash our system build.

How can I force emma to ignore these methods in the code coverage percentage?

Regards,

Felipe

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the [EMMA FAQ](http://emma.sourceforge.net/faq.html#q.executable):

> A feature to allow EMMA users to mark arbitrary methods as excluded from
>   coverage is being considered for future versions.

So unfortunately this doesn't seem to be possible at the moment. There's an [open feature request](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2948258&group_id=108932&atid=651900) for this in EMMA's tracker.

Comment: Any update on this? This answer is almost 3 years old already.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that every bit of code should be covered, including getters and setters, toString, equals and hash code.

I have seen many a pull requests with:

```
public void setName(String name)
{
   name = name; // instead of this.name = name
}
```

There are tools out there to help write these cumbersome tests. [ToStringVerifier](https://github.com/jparams/to-string-verifier) being one, [EqualsVerifier](https://jqno.nl/equalsverifier/) being another.