# How can I exclude methods from EMMA reports?

Tags: java, testing, code-coverage, emma

Is it possible to exclude selected methods from EMMA code coverage reports? I dont want to have getters, setters, `equals` methods, etc. in my final EMMA reports. I know that it is impossible to configure this in EMMA, but I'm hoping there is a trick which will allow me to skip those methods. I thought about modifying `coverage.em`, but I don't know the format of that file, or how to read it.

Comment: Some methods?  Which ones?  You're thinking of modifing files without knowledge of their format, perhaps the data you want isn't in the file.  It sounds like you need to clarify your question AND learn some more about what you are working with.  After you do both, odds are good you will ask an excellent question (or already have the answer).  As it stands, then only answer that can be given is "Yes! depending (with no further clarification)"

Comment: Which ones? As I wrote: methods like getters, setters, equals. I dont know format but from docummentation I can conclude that those information are in coverage.em I didnt found any information about format of this file. Hence my question how can I exclude those methods.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force Emma code coverage report to ignore some methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336711/how-to-force-emma-code-coverage-report-to-ignore-some-methods)